# histogram bars width with scale applied

Tags: csv, svg, d3.js

I successfully set up an histogram in d3, with scales and all, but I have a strange issue regarding the width of the rectangles of the bars. 
As the data I'm working with has very little values (eg. 0.0012), I need to apply scales to make them visible.
For the x-scale I set it up this way:

```
var domain = [0.00,0.01]
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(domain)
        .range([margin, width-margin]);
```

the histogram is called correctly with:

```
var histog = d3 .layout.histogram()
        .bins(35)
        (Peso);
```

where Peso is the variable parsing the data from the whole dataset (the console logs correctly the values).
Now to the problem: when I set up the bars, if I use these lines:

```
            svg.append("g")
            .attr("id", "Sans")
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(histog)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d,i) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return (height-margin) - (y(d.y)); })
            .attr("width", function (d) { return (d.dx); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
            .attr("fill", "lightblue")
            .attr("opacity", 0.5);
```

and the width, without the x-scale applied, is of course set to 1 px since the little values and intervals I have. The fact is that, if I apply the x-scale to the d.dx, the bars get a width that is too big and they overlay each other, like this:
[image: bars width completely wrong]

Is there something I am missing? Everything seems set up correctly to me, and I don't know what else could cause this. Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: don't use linear scales to determine position and width of the bars in a bar chart.

The linear scale maps its inputs linearly to the output range without considering any widths. What you need in this case (see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)) is an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal) that, in addition to doing the mapping, lets you get the output width associated with an input interval. This way, you call the scale to get the position of the bar and the width for an interval for the width of the bar.

Comment: ok, so now I need to figure out the domain values to get that correct! Thanks!

Comment: You could simply use all the values as in the example. Make sure that they're sorted before you pass them in. This also assumes that your distribution is even. Oh and you could also do it with a line that uses a step interpolation (which will make it look more like a histogram).

Comment: the distribution is not even, there are a couple of areas that are not covered by values, and I also thought of using a line to do that, but wasn't quite sure on how to do that, but that would be really cool since adding many bins to the d3.layout.histogram would render the line more and more accurate

Comment: It should be a straightforward line graph with the data that you have, i.e. use `d3.svg.line()` with suitable accessor functions for `x` and `y`.